# My ubuntu server won't allow loopback wget

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I have the following rules on my Ubuntu Server 14.04:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Flushing all rules
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 513:65535 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 --dport 513:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Forward 80 to 8080
iptables -I INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination SERVER_IP:8080
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j MARK --set-mark 1

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS lookup
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

And I'm unable to do a simple (connection refused):

```
wget http://www.example.com
```

or (connection refused):

```
wget http://localhost/
```

or even (stays idle):

```
wget http://localhost:8080
```

How do I fix my config in order to be able to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: When diagnosing such things, it is useful not to say `localhost`, but instead `127.0.0.1` or `::1` explicitly. This is because `localhost` often ends up resolving to `::1` on some systems. Where HTTP name-base virtual-hosting is in use, I frequently use `curl -H 'Host: www.example.com' http://127.0.0.1/...`

Answer (score 1):

Some of this was unnecessarily complicated (in particular, if you have a public webserver apparently on port 80, it makes little sense to try to prevent it being accessed via port 8080 if that's where it actually listens); additionally, you're only flushing the `filter` table in the beginning. (Also note that `-m state` is deprecated; newer iptables prefers `-m conntrack --ctstate`.)

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Flush all rules
for table in nat filter mangle; do
    iptables -F -t $table
    iptables -X -t $table
done

# Set default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow reply packets
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# DNAT 80 to 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d SERVER_IP --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination SERVER_IP:8080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d SERVER_IP --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination SERVER_IP:8080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d localhost --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination SERVER_IP:8080

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS lookup
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# ICMP is needed for pmtu discovery (could be more selective here, perhaps apply ratelimit):
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Log dropped packets for debugging, with a ratelimit
iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/minute -j LOG --log-prefix "FW: INPUT DROP: "
iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 5/minute -j LOG --log-prefix "FW: OUTPUT DROP: "

# flush conntrack table to make sure new rules are applied to existing connections (at the cost of interrupting them):
conntrack -F
```

If nothing else, the logging at the end should help determine what packets you're dropping that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your webserver is listening on the loopback port: `lsof -Pni:8080` should show at least one LISTENING socket, which should either be bound to IPv4 *:8080, IPv6 *:8080, or some set of specific interfaces such as 127.0.0.1:8080 and SERVER_IP:8080

Connection refused generally implies that there was nothing listening on that port, so check that the webserver is actually running and listening on that interface.

Remember also that your rule-set is only doing the DNAT for traffic coming in eth1, so make sure you test from outside your machine.

From localhost, you should be able to do a `curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8080/` or similar. Note that `localhost` does not always give you `127.0.0.1` on all systems, but will often give you `::1` first, so use `127.0.0.1` instead when testing.